# selecting radio button with almost same attributes in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

We have 2 radio buttons with almost same attributes and none of the combination of xpath atributes seem to work . Please help. Below is the HTML code added.

radio button 1:

```
<label class="label_radio r_off"><input kdfid="flowSelection" kdfapp="order" kdfpage="createOrder" type="radio" id="flowSelection" class="orderWithDealId" name="flowSelection" value="false" onclick="javascript:icw.singleEntry.flowSelection('deal');" checked="true" tabindex="1"></label>
<span class="radioTxt">With a Deal ID</span>
```

radio button 2:

```
<label class="label_radio r_on"><input kdfid="flowSelectionnew" kdfapp="order" kdfpage="createOrder" type="radio" id="flowSelectionnew" name="flowSelection" class="orderWithNoDealId" value="true" onclick="javascript:icw.singleEntry.flowSelection('noDeal');" tabindex="1"></label>
<span class="radioTxt">Without a Deal ID</span>
```

Please help.

Comment: Please the html code and other relevant details , also details on what you have tried so far.

Comment: What is the website

Comment: <label class="label_radio r_off"><input kdfid="flowSelection" kdfapp="order" kdfpage="createOrder" type="radio" id="flowSelection" class="orderWithDealId" name="flowSelection" value="false" onclick="javascript:icw.singleEntry.flowSelection('deal');" checked="true" tabindex="1"></label>            
 <span class="radioTxt">With a Deal ID</span>

Comment: 2nd radio button:                                                             <label class="label_radio r_on"><input kdfid="flowSelectionnew" kdfapp="order" kdfpage="createOrder" type="radio" id="flowSelectionnew" name="flowSelection" class="orderWithNoDealId" value="true" onclick="javascript:icw.singleEntry.flowSelection('noDeal');" tabindex="1"></label>                                
 <span class="radioTxt">Without a Deal ID</span>

Comment: its an internal application in the project so cannot share more details like website ??

Comment: Why can't you select the radio button based on the text?

Comment: Do they have similar tags like radiotxt?

Comment: driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'label_radio')]"))

Comment: are there multiple elements to the same xpath you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

```
//span[.='Without a Deal ID']/preceding-sibling::label/input
```

[image]

Comment: Try this xpath and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use xpath, className should work.

1. Try By.className("orderWithDealId") for the first radio button and By.className("orderWithNoDealId") for the second element.

   2. If you must use xpath, try "//input[@class='orderWithDealId']" for the first radio button and "//input[@class='orderWithNoDealId']" for the second radio button.
   3. You can also use the @value = true / false for the first and second radio buttons respectively.

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the elements you need to use `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *With a Deal ID* radio button using *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='radioTxt' and text()='With a Deal ID']//preceding::label[1]/input"))).click();
  ```
- *Without a Deal ID* radio button using *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='radioTxt' and text()='Without a Deal ID']//preceding::label[1]/input"))).click();
  ```